# Assist with modifying Python script

Tags: python, py2app

I am a beginner in Python and I require assistance in modifying a script. My objective is to create a Mac application that can change users' passwords and synchronize them with Azure AD tenants. Although the script runs without any error messages, I encounter a launch error when attempting to launch the application, as depicted in the attached image.
Python script:

1. Python script:

```
import subprocess
import requests
import json
import getpass
import os
import sys
from AppKit import NSAlert, NSApplication, NSCriticalAlertStyle, NSInformationalAlertStyle

CLIENT_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
TENANT_ID = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz'

def show_alert(title, message, style):
    alert = NSAlert.alloc().init()
    alert.setMessageText_(title)
    alert.setInformativeText_(message)
    alert.setAlertStyle_(style)
    alert.addButtonWithTitle_('OK')
    return alert.runModal()

def change_password(username):
    # Prompt for new password
    new_password = getpass.getpass('Enter your new password: ')

    # Change local macOS password
    subprocess.run(['dscl', '.', '-passwd', f'/Users/{username}', new_password])

    # Synchronize password with Azure AD
    endpoint = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/{TENANT_ID}/users/{username}/passwordProfile'
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(get_access_token())}
    payload = {
        'forceChangePasswordNextSignIn': False,
        'password': new_password
    }
    response = requests.patch(endpoint, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))

    if response.status_code == 204:
        show_alert('Success', 'Password changed successfully.', NSInformationalAlertStyle)
    else:
        show_alert('Error', 'Failed to change password.', NSCriticalAlertStyle)

def get_access_token():
    url = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token'
    payload = {
        'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
        'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
        'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
    }
    response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
    access_token = response.json().get('access_token')
    return access_token

def main():
    username = getpass.getuser()
    change_password(username)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = NSApplication.sharedApplication()
    main()
    sys.exit(app.run())
```

#To convert the script into an app#:

2. Install py2app:

```
pip install py2app
```

3. Create a setup.py file with the following contents:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    app=['password_app.py'],
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

4. Run the command to build the app bundle:

```
python setup.py py2app
```

[image: Launch Error]

I have tried to tweak the script but no luck.
I expect a working script

Comment: py -m pip install py2app --upgrade